# Campaigns - advanced setup

Tags: lightning, campaign, campaign-member

I created custom statuses in the Advanced Setup within Campaigns (SFDC, Classic). Do you know how to add this Advanced Setup to LEX? 
I found one doc (below link), but don't know how to add Campaign Member Status component to the Campaign view. I did search in the AppStore, but it's not there.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=campaigns_customize_member_status_lex.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

Advanced SetUp Button is not available in LEX. Alternatively you can add the related list "Campaign Member Statuses', to the pagelayout, which pretty much does the same thing.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=campaigns_customize_member_status_lex.htm&type=5